# How to get row key of last row added in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, thrift

Assuming that OrderPreservingPartitioner is used and rowkeys are strictly in ascending order, is there an easy way to get the row key of most recently added row using Cassandra client? I am aware the I can do a get_range_slices query to fetch all the rows and iterate till the end to find the last row key. But I feel that would be a time consuming operation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to get the last inserted rowkey even though they are in ascending order & OPP is used.

1. One naive solution would be storing the last inserted key in a file
   or some means like that. Don't think of cassandra for this :P
2. If you wanna be stuck with cassandra better store all inserted row keys of original CF (OCF) in a temporary CF (TCF) as columns. Make sure that `comparator` of your TCF is same as your `key_validation_class` of OCF

Solution 2 would keep the last inserted row_key of your OCF as the last column of a row in the TCF. You can use reverse range slice on a column to get the first from last ;)

```
SELECT FIRST 1 REVERSED * from TCF where KEY='yourkey'
```

You can control the size of the rows in Temporary_CF using expiry property of columns and modelling the data this way can give you an option of getting n row_keys inserted at the last too.

```
SELECT FIRST N REVERSED * from TCF where KEY='yourkey'
```

Answer (score 1):

Usage Pattern: we frequently need to load last added row

Implementation: "reverse" RowKey before serialization; use OrderPreservingPartitioner; use "timestamp" as a RowKey.

For instance, your RowKey is a long number (which represents timestamp). Then, use reverted (Long.MAX_VALUE - timestamp) for serialization of a timestamp. First row will be the last row inserted.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to know the last row beneath the detail of the timestamp across a network of nodes... I can't think of anything.

But cassandra resolves competing cell (row+column) updates by most-recent-timestamp-wins, so for all inserts also update a single column in a single row corresponding with that table, and query that cell with ALL. I recommend using a different row per columnfamily/table to prevent making that one row's updates too much of a bottleneck.

If there are two competing same-timestamp updates... well, we're probably down to philosophical questions at that point. Unless you want some slowdown point of a networked sequence generator, which sucks.

Dropping the consistency from ALL to QUORUM or ONE would probably speed things up a lot too for rapid row inserts, depending on how exact you need the result.